# Python Unicode Decode Error Using Package

Tags: python, cmd, package

I'm currently working on a data science package where you can analyze Whatsapp group information. Here is the link:https://github.com/aqeelanwar/AnalyzeTheChat/blob/master/README.md

I'm a beginner therefore I'm having some trouble with the last step where after entering this code

```py
main.py --path C:\Users\Usuario\Downloads\Panas.txt --save_as pdf
```

I'm getting a Unicode error message which I haven't been able to solve. I'm on a Windows 7, using anaconda on the cmd prompt.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "main.py", line 81, in 
> process_chat(args.path)
>
> File "main.py", line 42, in process_chat
> chat = chat.read()
>
> File "C:\Users\Usuario\anaconda3\envs\myenv1\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23
> , in decode
> return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
>
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 1769: character maps to

Comment: It would be good to include a code snippet instead of linking to the code. Also, check this question out it might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49045774/why-does-python3-get-a-unicodedecodeerror-reading-a-text-file-where-python2-does

Answer (score 0):

Python is treating the characters after the `\U` as Unicode. You can make Python treat the path like a string by putting another backslash before each backslash in the path, like `C:\\Users\\Usuario`.